# asp.net and javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am assigning a value to asp textbox in javascript as follows:

```
var tempStorytxt = document.getElementById("<%=txtStory.ClientID%>");
tempStorytxt.Value = TempValue;
alert(tempStorytxt.Value);
```

but when I access in codebehind as follows there is nothing in txtStory

```
 int StoryId = int.Parse(txtStory.Text);
```

Comment: when do you run your javascript code?

Comment: onchange of radio button

Comment: are you parsing the value on first load? If so, you won't get the value because server code behind runs first. The javascript will only assign the value after the page is loaded (depending on when you are actually running your script).

Comment: @pinoy_ISF please suggest me where to write this code

Comment: @pinoy_ISF int StoryId = int.Parse(txtStory.Text); this line is inside button click event of a button

Answer (score 0):

Use small V as **txtStorytxt.value** not ***txtStorytxt.Value***

Comment: But when i use alert(tempStorytxt.Value); it gives me correct value in alert box

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
document.getElementById("<%= txtStory.ClientID%>").value = TempValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" OnClientClick="setVal()" OnClick="btnTest_Click" Text="Test" />
```

your js function;

```
 function setVal()
 {
   var tempStorytxt = document.getElementById("<%=txtStory.ClientID%>");
   tempStorytxt.setAttribute("value", tempValue);
   alert(tempStorytxt.getAttribute("value"));
 }
```

and in button click event;

```
 int StoryId = int.Parse(txtStory.Text);
```